# How to fine tune what .NET MAUI iOS SDK to be targeted?

Tags: macos, sdk, maui

I have built a .NET MAUI lib and Nuget, targeting .NET 8. I did so on my PC but when I try and install the Nuget in MAUI projects on the Mac, I get this:

```
Package my.MAUI.lib 1.0.0-beta.29 is not compatible with net8.0-ios17.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package my.MAUI.lib 1.0.0-beta.29 supports:
  - net8.0-android34.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
  - net8.0-ios17.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
  - net8.0-maccatalyst17.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
  - net8.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
```

The MAUI lib, that builds the Nuget, is targeting like so (from lib .csproj):

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
<UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
<SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

Is the problem related to what SDKs are installed in MacOS? if so, here's what I have:

```
3.1.409 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.418 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.419 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.420 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.426 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.203 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.407 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.106 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.202 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.406 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.407 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.416 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.417 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.200 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.202 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.203 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.310 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.311 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
8.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
8.0.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

[EDIT]
Updating the MAUI workload on the Mac fixed the issue so, apparently, my build environment now support net8.0-ios17.2. However, for possible future similar issues, and to improve my know-how, is there a way to control which workload is being targeted while building the Nuget?

Comment: Did you solve the issue on how to target an specific net8.0-ios version or how to target only net8.0-ios with all its versions?

Comment: I still haven't figured that out, no